# The entry disappeared in NSDictionary returning from JSContext

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsnumber, javascriptcore

Give a `JSContext`

```
    JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];
    context[@"directReturn"] = ^id(NSString *name) {
        id obj = @{@(2): @"test", @"testKey": @"testValue"};
        return obj;
    };
```

And call it:

```
    JSValue *jsValue = [context evaluateScript:@"directReturn()"];
    obj = jsValue.toObject;
    NSLog(@"jscore: %@", obj);
```

The output is:

```
jscore: {
    testKey = testValue;
}
```

We can see that the first entry which using `NSNumber` as key disappeared.

Why the first entry disappeared?

Comment: It's probably because object property names in JS should be strings and not integers

Answer (score 0):

Base on the source code of JavaScriptCore, it only allows keys of type `NSString` to be converted into js objects.

[image: JavaScriptCore]